# Launch a bash script from the dock

Tags: dock, bash

I can't seem to figure this one out, there must be some really easy trick.

I have a bash script which sets my environment for an app and launches it with the correct parameters.  How can I put this script (or any script) on the dock?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

Automator can be used to create an application "wrapper" around a script, so that you can launch your script like any other application (and it won't spawn a superfluous Terminal window in the process).

1. Open Automator, and create a new **application** type workflow.
2. Add a **Run Shell Script** action, and enter your script into the text field.
3. If your script takes input (such as files), make sure the **Pass input** setting on the action is set appropriately (either arguments, if you use `$1, $2, etc.` or stdin). Otherwise you can ignore this setting.
4. Save the workflow to your location of choice, then drop the resulting file in the Dock.